# How to implement Hammer.js for the swipe event for devices without mouse

Tags: mouseevent, swipe, hammer.js

How can I implement Hammer.js to catch only swipeLeft and swipeRight events on devices without mouse?

In the source code of hammer.js I found that a var **INPUT_TYPE_MOUSE = 'mouse';** exists. In the documentation I did not find how to disable it with the options.

Have I to disable all recognizers in a preset if I only want to use the swipe recognizer?

```
 preset: [
// RecognizerClass, options, [recognizeWith, ...], [requireFailure, ...]
[RotateRecognizer, { enable: false }],
[PinchRecognizer, { enable: false }, ['rotate']],
[SwipeRecognizer,{ direction: DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }],
[PanRecognizer, { direction: DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }, ['swipe']],
[TapRecognizer],
[TapRecognizer, { event: 'doubletap', taps: 2 }, ['tap']],
[PressRecognizer]
],
```

How can I do this by the options?

Answer (score 0):

To use only Swipe recognizer you can do this:

```
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(element, managerOptions);
mc.add(new Hammer.Swipe(recognizerOptions));
mc.on('swipeleft', leftSwipeHandler);
mc.on('swiperight', rightSwipeHandler);
```

It's described in [More Control Section](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/#more-control) in documentation.

This will recognize swipe not only in touch devices but also in those that use mouse. I don't know how to disable firing this event in mouse devices. But I think that after event's been fired you can check in handler function what kind of pointer caused the event. Use event's `pointerType` property for that purpose:

```
var leftSwipeHandler = function (event) {
  if (event.pointerType === 'mouse')
    return;
  // some more code
}
```

If you use jquery plugin then this property is in `gesture` object: `event.gesture.pointerType`.